# Is it possible to create a drop down in Excel with no text just color options to fill a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, I would like to create a dropdown with no text only color options to fill the cell. I'd like to give only a few specific options to the user, for convenience and simplicity.

It would also facilitate my VBA coding because I'm using `cells().Interior.ColorIndex` to identify the color and do certain tasks depending on the color chosen. So, I suppose I'm restricted by the 56 colors in the index color pallet of Excel.

Is this possible?

Comment: I've tried doing this before a long time ago. Don't think it is possible. Great question though, hoping someone has the answer!

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if someone could figure it out!

Comment: Actually I cannot recommend doing things in VBA based on colors. There are several disadvantages (more complicated, slower, etc). Also the users would need to know what a color means to choose. So I highly recommend to use keywords instead (also think of colorblind people) and put a conditional formatting with a color on each keyword in a supportive matter.

Comment: I understand what you mean Peh and I agree a bit. But actually the colors in this specific project don't mean anything, is just to fill hours and differentiate activities in a calendar. So I think the idea is good. If a client is colorblind then we would have to do a modification on the colors, but it would work anyway.

Comment: Why not using eg letter A-Z as values and put a conditional formatting so A gets red, B gets blue, …? Would be easier to handle in VBA and would work with the drop down box.

Comment: Think you'd need to make something from scratch e.g. a button which then shows a bunch of hidden buttons of the colors you want. You could even animate the buttons being rolled out like a combo box list opening using a timer (set position down a bit, wait a few ms, loop until in the final position). Alternatively you could use the windows color picker: https://exceloffthegrid.com/calling-and-using-the-color-picker-with-vba/

Comment: I was working along the same lines as what @Pᴇʜ has suggested, but the dropdown only ever displays the text ie black on white... the conditional formatting works well though.

Comment: @Peh thank you for the idea. I'm doing something similar for now but with the names of the colors.

Comment: @Absinthe that's an interesting idea but it's not applicable to what I need.

Comment: What's that? Maybe the idea could be modified?

Comment: Using a helper selection and conditional formatting can get something moderately similar, but I can't see how you would do a colour list without trying to create a dropdown sub-classed class module. For the former - this may be useful: https://www.contextures.com/excelconditionalformattingcolor.html

Comment: Thank you @Tragamor I did something similar but I think is better, which is creating a drop down menu with the color names and a Conditiontal Formatting which converts the text and fill color of the cell to that specific color. The result is a cell with only the color. I downsized the font size to 1, so I can use this cells as squares. The result is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't accomplish what I wanted 100% but with the help of Stackoverflow developers I got to a pretty cool result which works perfectly for what I wanted and it could probably be useful for someone else.

So what I did was a drop down menu with the colour names and a Conditiontal Formatting which converts the text and fill of the cell to the specific colour. I downsized the font size to 1, so I can use them as small rectangles.

[image]